# Rails / Trix Editor save changes via AJAX to server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix

I am using the very simple to implement [Trix Editor](https://github.com/basecamp/trix) provided from Basecamp in an "Edit View".

How would one save automatically changes, without having the user to interact through the update button?

I am thinking about something like this:
**(OLD SCRIPT)**

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    localStorage["editorState"] = JSON.stringify(element.editor)
}, 5000);
```

**What I actually want to do:**

post a ajax "post" request to the rails server. something like:

```
$('trix-editor').on('blur', function() {

    var sendname = $('#note_name').val();
    var sendlink = $('#linkinput').val();
    var sendnote = $('input[name="note[note]"]').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/notes",
        data: { note: { name: sendname, link: sendlink, note: sendnote } },
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.id);
            return false;
        },
            error: function(data) {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

(There is as well the problem with authentification and devise. Only if you are loged in you should be able to send an ajax post request ..??)

Even better would be to save changes only when the user changes some data, and then wait 5s and then push the updated data via json to the server. I have no clue how to do that...

PS: would have loved to tag this question with a "trix-editor" tag, sorry have not enought rep for doing so...

Comment: I've updated the syntax for my answer. It's a bit tricky. Without the hidden input field, you are not getting the plain text for your trix-editor. You have to access the text with the id from the trix-editor, not from the hidden input field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using plain JavaScript, use a [hidden input field](https://github.com/basecamp/trix#integrating-with-forms):

```
<form>
  <input type="hidden" id="noticeEditorContent"/>
  <trix-editor input="noticeEditorContent" id="x" style="min-height: 200px;"></trix-editor>
</form>
```

**Now you have access to the element with the ID x.**

Which means, with getElementById, you can do something like that:

```
var richTex = document.getElementById("x");
```

With this variable, you can either set an interval as you already explained, or you are using jQuery to do the job:

```
$('#x').on('input', function() {
    localStorage["editorState"] = JSON.stringify($('#x').val());
});
```

*Just a suggestion. You can write this code a bit nicer and cleaner.*

Now it depends. Is setting an interval every 5 seconds better or writing every change to the LocalStorage?

**Suggestion:**
Save the input when the user deselects the field:

```
$('#x').on('blur', function() {
  localStorage["editorState"] = JSON.stringify($('#x').val());
});
```

Update: Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uqd7xtg8/23/).

Comment: thanks for the response. Getting the element via jquery works pretty good. unfortunately I posted a missleading script, i don't wont to save to the browsers localstorage, instead i would like to send a ajax "post" request. See the edited post.

Answer (score 0):

so I came up with this code which saves via ajax on 'trix-blur' (which fires when the user disselects the trix-editor). There is only the question left if this code is secure enought with devise, or if now anyone can send data to be saved?!?

I have the authentification in the notes controller like that:

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

and here is the javascript part (with a custom messages functionality):

```
$('trix-editor').on('trix-blur', function() {

    var sendname = $('#note_name').val();
    var sendlink = $('#linkinput').val();
    var sendnote = $('input[name="note[note]"]').val();
    var sendid = $('#note_id').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/notes/" + sendid,
        dataType: "json",
        data: { note: { name: sendname, link: sendlink, note: sendnote }, id: sendid, commit:  "Update Note" },
        success: function(data) {
            addMessage('auto saved ...', 'msg-success');
            return false;
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('error');
            return false;
        }
    });

    var addMessage = function(msg, msgclass) {
        $('#notifications').append('<div id="msg" class="msg '+msgclass+'">'+msg+'</div>');
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#msg:last-child').addClass('msgvisible');    
        }, 100);
        displayMessage();
    };

    var displayMessage = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            hideMessage();
        }, 2000);
    };

    var hideMessage = function() {
        $('#msg').addClass('msghide');
        setTimeout( function() {
            deleteMessage();
        }, 300);
    };


    var deleteMessage = function() {
        $('#msg').remove();
        if ($('#notificatosn').find('#msg') > 1) {
            displayMessage();
        }
    };


});
```

Comment: Almost there. You can also use the `trix-change` event that emits when the content of the editor changes.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Trix project page](https://github.com/basecamp/trix) the `trix-editor` emits different events on specific conditions.

The `trix-change` event is what you need; it fires whenever the editor’s contents has changed.

So, the first line of your JavaScript code could be

```js
$('trix-editor').on('trix-change', function() {
  /* Here will be your code to save the editor's contents. */
})
```